# Error when compiling mac os java file in ms windows

Tags: java, windows, macos

I have a number of student with java programming assigment written using (most probabaly) Mac OS.

The trouble here is I can't compile their code (in Windows) to see the executable output. I have open the file and there is nothing different in it (except it is slightly bigger than the same file written in Windows).

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here? Is the because the meta-data at the background or something else?

*Update ~ here is the error message that were produced*

```
                                                ☺   ☺        ▲This resource
```

fork intentionally left blank

```
                                                                ☺   ☺
```

▲         ∟ ▲  →
       ^
me._Application.java:1: illegal character: \0
 ♣▬ ☻  Mac OS X         ☻          2  ♫░   ☻  ♫Γ  ☺▲
      ATTR;Ü╔   ♫Γ   ╚  ☺‼               ☻   ╚   F  §com.apple.quarantine   ☺♫
 ═  %com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms 0000;4e893bff;Mail;40818AA2-9460-4D93-
B3B8-1ED961B2F468|com.apple.mailbplist00ú☺☻♥*►,Neil Drum-Garcia* ►↑Compsci 101 Assignment 2_►Pmessage:%3CCAEKp0axAAFq4O5quHs-O69e4exN
uMrjAeUU_GtoMn498Nto+ag@mail.gmail.com%3♀;V      ☺☺       ♦               ⌐

Cheers..

Comment: Not unless you tell us the error message. However, -encoding MacRoman might be the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. I've update my question with the error message. Can you tell me more how to encode MacRoman? This is the first time I heard it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably got files in the directory labelled `._classFile.java`, which are being interpreted by `javac`. They contain the resource fork information for the file when stored on a non Mac OS system. The quick solution is to delete these files before attempting to compile the code in the directory.

Comment: I had a similar problem but the ._classsName files were scattered all over my project and not confined to a specific folder. the way I fixed it was by searching for all .java files, sorting by name and deleting all files that started with ._